# How to configure JwtBearer with mandatory claim?

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt

My application logic depends on a claim existing, hence this claim is mandatory and needs to always be present in the token.

I am not interested in a [Authorization Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies) since policies applies to different users and this is a mandatory claim required to be present in all tokens.

Right now my controllers contains:

```cs
    private const string MyCustomClaim = "foo";
    private string _myCustomClaim;

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        _myCustomClaim = context.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(MyCustomClaim)?.Value;
    }
```

If the field `_myCustomClaim` is `null` then things will fail later.
I could add a null check and throw an exception, but it would be better if the Authorization middleware did not authorize the user if the token did not contain the claim.

Is there any way to inform the Authorization middleware that a certain claim is mandatory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Startup.cs` file when configuring the authentication middleware handle the `OnTokenValidated` event.

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnTokenValidated = context =>
        {
            const string claimTypeFoo = "foo";
            if (!context.Principal.HasClaim(c => c.Type == claimTypeFoo))
            {
                context.Fail($"The claim '{claimTypeFoo}' is not present in the token.");
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
});
```

#### This could also be done in a class:

File `Startup.cs`

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.Events = new MyJwtBearerEvents();
});
```

File `MyJwtBearerEvents.cs`

```cs
public class MyJwtBearerEvents : JwtBearerEvents
{
    private const string ClaimTypeFoo = "foo";

    public override Task TokenValidated(TokenValidatedContext context)
    {
        if (!context.Principal.HasClaim(c => c.Type == ClaimTypeFoo))
        {
            context.Fail($"The claim '{ClaimTypeFoo}' is not present in the token.");
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: My context class doesn't seem to have a Fail method. What version of DotNetCore are you using?

Comment: I use ASP.NET Core 2.0. -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticateresult?view=aspnetcore-2.0